# How do I find the one intersection of $\sqrt[p]{x}$ and $\ln(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, interpolation

$y=\sqrt{x}$ and $y=\ln(x)$ have no points of intersection for $x>0$, while $y=\sqrt[3]{x}$ and $y=\ln(x)$ have $2$ such intersection points with $x>0$.

$y=\sqrt[p]{x}$ and $y=\ln(x)$ have exactly one point of intersection (for $x>0$).

Find $p$ and $x_0$.

Comment: Please use MathJax to type mathematical expressions. And what have you tried to find $p$ and $x_0$? You are more likely to get response if you show you've made an effort.

Answer (score 0):

Your question shouldn't have solution. Let me explain: for every $x\in[0,1]$, $x^{1/p}>\log(x)$. Moreover

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt[p]x} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{p}\frac{1}{x^{(p-1)/p}}} = \lim_{x\to\infty}p \frac{x^{(p-1)/p}}{x} =\lim_{x\to\infty} p \frac{1}{\sqrt[p] x} = 0 .
$$

This results means that, given $p$, there exists $M>0$ such that

$$
\sqrt[p] x >\log (x) \qquad \forall x>M .
\tag{$\ast$}
$$

So we have: for $0<x<1$ 
$$
\sqrt[p] x >\log (x) 
$$
and for $x>M$
$$
\sqrt[p] x >\log (x) .
$$

If exists a point $01x_0<M$ such that

$$
\sqrt[p]{x_0} = \log(x_0)
$$
and that 
$$
\sqrt[p]{x} = \log(x)
$$
for $x\in(x_0,x_0+\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon>0$ enough small, then it must exist $x_0<x_0'<M$ such that
$$
\sqrt[p]{x} = \log(x)
$$
and
$$
\sqrt[p]{x} >\log(x)
$$
for $x\in(x_0',x_0'+\epsilon')$, otherwise equation$(*)$ doens't hold. So intersection points appear in pairs.

However, I can't proof there is no point in which both functions have the same tangent line, and I'm not sure how to disprove that.

Answer (score 0):

My instinct would be reverse the variables $x$ and $y$, so that you are looking at the inverse functions $y=x^p$ and $y=e^x$. You are seeking intersection points $x^p=e^x$.

This is equivalent to finding the zeros of $f(x)=e^x-x^p$. Evidently there are two zeros whenever this continuous function successfully dips below the $x$-axis, giving a solution on the way down and another on the way up.

There is a clear location where $p=e$ where you can show that $e^x-x^e\ge0$ and equality only when $x=e$.

Because I swapped $y$ and $x$, the answer to the original problem occurs when $p=e$ and $y_0=e$ and $x_0=e^e$.